# custom font not showing properly using @font-face

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

After much review, I can't get the correct display of a custom font I created through fontsquirrel. Chrome's Inspector shows the icon is in place but all I get is this default icon box ;o(
Rails 4 app, Bootstrap

[image]

Any ideas?

application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

html:

```
<div class="hatfont icon-balloon01"></div>
```

here's my CSS:

```
hatfont {
  font-family: 'haticon';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  div {
    font-family: haticon;
  }
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'haticon';
  src:assets-url('fonts/haticon.eot');
  src:assets-url('fonts/haticon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    assets-url('fonts/haticon.woff') format('woff'),
    assets-url('fonts/haticon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    assets-url('fonts/haticon.svg#haticon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: 'haticon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-graphs:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
```

[image: Here's my current tree for font folders]

Comment: Check your rails log file, there should be an exception

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before myself. I can't identify the problem specifically from what you've provided, but a few things come to mind. Check your link references in your CSS. Make sure no files were moved and that your stylesheet is in the same directory as your fonts folder. Also, the %> under your font-face looks out of place... I don't know if that's a Rails thing or not. Here's an example of something that I've used before that's worked. Obviously, you'd need to substitute your font files. :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Good tip on ensuring the location of the CSS files within the same directory. I moved some things around - but still working on it. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck. Feel free to post back when you identify the problem. I'm curious to see if that was it or something else.

Comment: how does the file structure pic above look?

Comment: Are you still having an issue with it? Your file structure looks good... assuming that your CSS is being referenced correctly in the page document and the CSS is located in haticon.css.scss, you can probably eliminate the file locations as the issue.  If you're still having issues, I would create a simple HTML page that references your haticon.css.scss file without any JSON or Rails implementation. If your fonts display, then you've eliminated the CSS references as the issue.

Comment: Still scratching my head. With the above scenario, the default square box disappeared. If I used the haticon CSS in the _utilities scss file, then the default box came back. I'll try what you mentioned. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickLightning im having same issue, nothing worked for me. did you figure it out